# Firefox Extensions HTML Injection on the fly?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Hi I followed the instructions to create an extension.

My issue is that I can inject text on the fly but not HTML. Firefox block the character "<"

Here is my code in my XUL file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<overlay id="sample" 
         xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

<script src="jquery.js" /> 

<script>


var myExtension = {
init: function() {
    // The event can be DOMContentLoaded, pageshow, pagehide, load or unload.
    if(gBrowser) gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", this.onPageLoad, false);
},
onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {
    var doc = aEvent.originalTarget; // doc is document that triggered the event
    var win = doc.defaultView; // win is the window for the doc
         if (win != win.top) return; //only top window.
         $("body",doc).html('WORK');
         $("body",doc).html('<div>NOT WORKING</div>');
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load", function() { myExtension.init(); }, false);
</script>    
</overlay>
```

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a XUL file, it has to use XML syntax. In particular, XML tags inside `<script>` elements will be interpreted as such - and you definitely don't want it. To prevent it you can wrap your script into a [CDATA section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA):

```xml
<script>
<![CDATA[
  doSomething("<foo>bar</foo>");
]]>
</script>
```

This makes sure that the tag contents are really interpreted as text.

Comment: Perfect it's working like  charm. I found another way to do it by putting the script in an other file myscript.js and include this file in the XUL.